# I need to replace '/net/local_folder/apps/images' with '/net/local_folder/unknown_app_location/images' in PLSQL and PGSQL

Tags: oracle, postgresql, plsql

I need to replace '/net/local_folder/apps/images' with '/net/local_folder/unknown_app_location/images' in PLSQL and PGSQL.
Whatever the string which comes after 'local_folder/' and before '/images' which is 'apps' in the above string, I want to replace it with new string in both
PLSQL and PGSQL.

Ex1:

```
input : '/net/local_folder/apps/images' 
output: '/net/local_folder/application/images'
```

Ex2:

```
input : '/net/local_folder/applications/images' 
output: '/net/local_folder/apps_folder/images'
```

Comment: Why do you think you need a stored procedure? This can be done in plain SQL using the `replace()` function

Answer (score 0):

Can't tell about PostgreSQL, but - in Oracle, one option might be

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select '/net/local_folder/apps/images'          from dual union all
  3     select '/net/local_folder/applications/images'  from dual
  4    )
  5  select col,
  6    regexp_replace(col, 'local_folder/\w+/images', 'local_folder/' || '&par_folder' || '/images') result
  7  from test;
Enter value for par_folder: unknown_folder

COL                                   RESULT
------------------------------------- ----------------------------------------
/net/local_folder/apps/images         /net/local_folder/unknown_folder/images
/net/local_folder/applications/images /net/local_folder/unknown_folder/images

SQL>
```